# why php loop doesn't appear with all values & concatenated html?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, concatenation

Please check out php code given below.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'unityaccess');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "connection failed";
  exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM  players ORDER BY id DESC";

$row_result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row_result)){
  $card = '<div class="card">';
   $card .= '<div class="card-body">';
   $card .= '<div class="comment-header">';
   $card .= '<h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 comment-name">'.$record['name'].'&nbsp;</h6>';
   $card .= '</div>';
   $card .= '</div>';
   $card .= '</div>';

}
?>
```

I want to loop all name values inside html cards. according to loop there have 7 all name values. when I echo them it will loop correctly. but when I concatenate & **echo** `$card` like follows.

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 comment-section">
        <h4>Comments</h4>
        <?php
          echo $card;
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Then I can only show first value of `name` attribute. Why I can't retrieve all the name values with card. I think code looks not bad anyway.

Comment: "when I concatenate"  Please show the code where you're doing that

Comment: you can see $card with .= marks

Comment: Right, but you're not concatenating the _result_.  You're creating a new `$card` each time

Answer (score 1):

change

```
  $card = '<div class="card">';
```

with

```
   $card .= '<div class="card">';
```

*It is a good practice to initialize your variables, if you don't the PHP engine will do a type cast depending on variable usage.

Comment: you mean first one

Comment: Yes, you are overwriting the string without it.

Comment: Thank you. Its when I learn it, it showed first one without concatenation.

Comment: Tom, you also have to remind the OP that the `$card` variable has to be initialised outside the loop before you can concatenate into `$card` inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the `$card` variable each time round the loop, so all you are left with after the loop is the last card.

```
$row_result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$card = ''; // init the card variable, so you can use `.=` from here on

while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row_result)){
    //$card = '<div class="card">';    this was the offending line
    $card .= '<div class="card">';
    $card .= '  <div class="card-body">';
    $card .= '      <div class="comment-header">';
    $card .= '          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 comment-name">'.$record['name'].'&nbsp;</h6>';
    $card .= '      </div>';
    $card .= '  </div>';
    $card .= '</div>';
}
```